# Repeating observations in quantum theory

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-information, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, observables

Suppose we prepare a state $\psi$ in a quantum system, represented in some Hilbert space, and suppose $A$ is an observable represented by the matrix $A$ (which possibly has infinite order).

**QUESTION A**

What is the "physical" difference between making an observation through $A$, or $A^m$ (or, in other words, $m$ times $A$ repeatedly), where $m$ is any positive integer ?

Since $A$ and $A^m$ commute, they have the same complete basis of eigenstates, so the outcome of the measurement seems to give the same eigenvalue up to a power ($m$), after collapsing into the same eigenstate.

But has this any *physical* meaning ? How is measuring through $A^m$ different from measuring through $A$ ?

**QUESTION B**

Now suppose that $A^m$ is the identity operator for some $m$.

Same question ?

Comment: Repeating the measurement of $A$ for $m$ times is not the same as measuring $A^m$.

Comment: You can measure $A$, say, write its value $a$ on  a piece of paper and then calculate $a^m$. This is the "instrument" that measures $A^m$.

Comment: @Quillo No, that's incorrect. Measurement of $A^m$ would, in general, be different from the measurement of $A$ because even if the measured eigenvalues are $a^m$ and $a$ respectively, the post-measurement state-vector will, in general, be different depending on whether you measure $A$ or $A^m$.

Comment: @DvijD.C. aren't eigenstates of $A$ and $A^m$ the same?

Comment: @Quillo They can be arranged to have the shared eigenstates but the projection operators onto their eigensubspaces need not be the same.

Comment: @DvijD.C. if they have the same eigenspaces the projector is the same (this happens for example if both $A$ and $A^m$ are non degenerate). "Question B" in is an example of this kind of "complication", so the trick of multiplying $a$ still works but not the projection procedure. Please correct me, many years since QM.

Comment: @Quillo Saying that they have the same eigensubspaces is just repeating that they have the same projectors. Yes, the "complication" would arise when one is degenerate w.r.t. the other. It's not that the "projection procedure" doesn't work, it's that you are literally measuring two physically distinct observables in that case -- as evident by the different post-measurement states.

Comment: As an example, consider measuring the z component of spin for a spin 1/2 system, or measuring its square (which is represented by the identity matrix).

Comment: @THC, how do you define the power of (the self-adjoint) A? (Let us simplify and assume finite-dimensional, or at least bounded, so no issue with domain.) If it is on the basis of mathematics -- using functional calculus -- then the physical content between the two should be the same (determined by the spectral measure). If you are referring to a physical experiment whereby a meaning (and measurement) to $A^m$ can be given *without* necessarily doing so for A, please explain. Thanks.

Comment: @MahirLokvancic: if $A$ is the matrix corresponding to my initial observable, then I want to consider the observable defined by the matrix $A^m$. I am equally interested in repeating the measurement by the observable $A$, $m$ times. Is the outcome the same as measuring one time through $A^m$ ?

Comment: The observable defined by $A^m$ is as stated by Quilo. Re the 2nd, it is not the same as 1st (as stated by Dvij D.C.); rather, before the measurement of $A$, $m$ times, you need to distinguish two cases, to begin: an ensemble of $m$ equally prepared initial states on each of which you measure $A$ (or, equivalently, "re-preparing" it after each measurement of $A$, in sequence) vs just doing it one after the other (when you will keep getting the same eigenvalue obtained in the first measurement -- as long as you don't wait too long or mess up the system in between the successive measurements).

Comment: @MahirLokvancic: thanks ! You mean the $m$th power of the eigenvalue, right (when repeating one after the other) ? I have seen in many discussions on the position and momentum operators $\hat{p}$ and $\hat{m}$, that the operator $[\hat{p}^n,\hat{m}]$ is used to show that at least one of $\hat{p}, \hat{m}$ is not bounded. Which operator is meant by $\hat{p}^n$ in this particular (important) discussion ?

Comment: In the first case (measuring the observable defined by $A^m$) the eigenvalues should be the $m$-th powers of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: In the second case (measuring $A$, $m$ times) there are a few flavors to this, depending how you prepare each of the individual $m$ measurements. I will just consider two obvious possibilities. Case 1 (in each of the $m$ measurements, you prepare the same initial state). Then the individual outcomes will in general be random (unless the initial state happens to be an eigenvector), and for large $m$, the average of the values should converge (at least, in theory) to the expected value of $A$ for the given (initial) state.

Comment: Case 2 (you prepare an initial state, then, just keep measuring $A$, $m$ times, without any modification of the state/eigenvector "in between"). When you do the first measurement (with $m-1$ remaining), then you will get a random eigenvalue (and eigenvector) of $A$. In each of the subsequent $m-1$ measurements of $A$ you will get exactly the same eigenvalue (so, no randomness). This assumes you do not wait too long in between the successive measurements, and that the system is very well insulated.

Comment: The important point (as noted above by @DvijD.C.) is that the measurement -- and the meaning -- of $A^m$ is not the same as measuring $A$, $m$ times.

Comment: @MahirLokvancic: great ! So I guess the operator $\hat{p}^n$ (see my previous comment) is of the first type (the observable defined by $P^n$ if the matrix $P$ represents $\hat{p}$) ?

Comment: Yes. As usual, nothing is without caveats, so as long as you stay with finite dimensional Hilbert space, or at least work with bounded (self-adjoint or normal) operators, it should be fine. However, there are some tricky issues with domain when it comes to the operators defined on infinite-dimensional spaces. Nevertheless, powers or polynomials (of the operators) can for "every-day purpose" be considered OK.